# how to use LIKE in search in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-like

```
def self.search_by(search_term)

   where("LOWER (course_name) LIKE :search", search_term: "%#{search_term}%")
end
```

this is my code, it seems LIKE query doesn't work at all

Comment: What is not working?

Answer (score 2):

Your code `where("LOWER (course_name) LIKE :search", search_term: "%#{search_term}%")` isn't working because it's expecting an argument `search` but you're passing `search_term`. So, modify it to:

`where("LOWER (course_name) LIKE :search", search: "%#{search_term}%")`
now you're providing the same variable which it's expecting to get in `"LOWER (course_name) LIKE :search"`.

Answer (score 0):

@venues = Venue.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{@query}%")

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :search_by, -> (search_term){ where("LOWER(course_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search_term.to_downcase}%")}
```

OR

```
def self.search_by(search_term)
  where("LOWER(course_name) LIKE ?", "%#{search_term.to_downcase}%")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

### update your query to

where("LOWER (course_name) LIKE :**search_term**", **search_term**: "%#{**search_term**}%")

change the :search keyword with :search_term , you used alias :search in query but specify :search_term to assign search value.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `ILIKE` can be used instead of `LIKE` to match case-insensitive strings, so you don't have to use `LOWER`.

Also, the reason your query is not working is that you have to change the `:search_term` alias with `:search`.

```
def self.search_by(search_term)
   where("course_name ILIKE :search", search: "%#{search_term}%")
end
```